# Installing and enabling both master and slave semisynchronous plugins on same server

Tags: mysql, replication, my.cnf, semi-sync-replication

I want to run a semisynchronous replication setup, and for simplicity I'd like to not have to INSTALL and UNINSTALL plugins when a slave is promoted to a master. So I'm wondering if I'll experience any problems having *both* master and slave plugins installed and enabled (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync-installation.html))

It looks like after installing the second plugin, both variables [`rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled) and [`rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled) are reset to off (the non-default). When I include these lines in `my.cnf`:

```
loose-rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled = 1
loose-rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled = 1
```

...and restart MySQL, both plugins are loaded and enabled.

Is this going to cause any problems for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not cause any problems. I have always setup all MySQL 5.5. DB servers for clients with both plugins. In fact, I answered a question back on Aug 05, 2011 where I posted an update on Aug 08, 2011 on how to install both plugins at the same time

Please see [Is MySQL Replication Affected by a High-Latency Interconnect?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/is-mysql-replication-affected-by-a-high-latency-interconnect/4390#4390)

Here is the excerpt from that update

## EXCERPT

The configuration of MySQL 5.5 Semisynchronous Replication is straightforward

Step 1) Add these four(4) lines to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin
#rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled
#rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=5000
#rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled
```

Step 2) Restart MySQL

```
service mysql restart
```

Step 3) Run these commands in the MySQL client

```
INSTALL PLUGIN rpl_semi_sync_master SONAME 'semisync_master.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN rpl_semi_sync_slave  SONAME 'semisync_slave.so';
```

Step 4) Uncomment the three rpm_semi_sync options after the plugin-dir option

```
[mysqld]
plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin
rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled
rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=5000
rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled
```

Step 5) Restart MySQL

```
service mysql restart
```

All Done !!! Now just setup MySQL Replication as usual.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I think the `loose` prefix is a pretty nice way to avoid commenting and uncommenting those config lines.