# which mysql version to use - 5.1 or 5.5?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5, best-practices, mysql-5.1

I am designing a new database. There are going to be around 1000 write queries per second. There may be as much as 10000 read per second.

Which MySQL version is recommended?

I came across a post on this site which says that 5.5 might be slower than 5.1 in some cases but some tuning will make it good enough. If tuning is done, then is it advisable to use 5.5? Or 5.1 performs better?

### Edit

Here's the link to the post I referred to above - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202825/mysql-5-5-perfomance

Comment: 5.6 is not officially released ("GA" - general availability) yet

Comment: Ok. edited my question. I think 5.5 should be the preferred choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no substitute of tuning MySQL. [Left unconfigured, there are cases when even MySQL 4.1 outperforms MySQL 5.x on the same level playing field](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/10/10/mysql-versions-shootout/).

Here are my past posts on the subject

- `Oct 05, 2011` : [Query runs a long time in some newer MySQL versions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/query-runs-a-long-time-in-some-newer-mysql-versions/6542#6542)
- `Nov 24, 2011` : [Why mysql 5.5 slower than 5.1 (linux,using mysqlslap)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/why-mysql-5-5-slower-than-5-1-linux-using-mysqlslap/8385#8385)
- `Feb 08, 2012` : [MySQL 5.5 perfomance (**StackOverflow**)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202825/mysql-5-5-perfomance/9202860#9202860)
- `Feb 22, 2012` : [MySQL 5.1 vs MySQL 5.5 (5.1 twice as fast) (**ServerFault**)](https://serverfault.com/questions/362388/mysql-5-1-vs-mysql-5-5-5-1-twice-as-fast/362706#362706)
- `Jul 16, 2012` : [decreased performance of stored procedure when migrated from mysql server 5.0 to 5.5](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/decreased-performance-of-stored-procedure-when-migrated-from-mysql-server-5-0-to/20977#20977)

## Bottom Line

You should always use the most stable release of MySQL because there are just certain bug and features that are fixed that do not carry over to the next major release.

Note that

- MySQL 5.0 is up to 5.0.96, but the bugs that MySQL 5.5 Addressed still reside in 5.0.96
- MySQL 5.1 is up to 5.1.67, but the bugs that MySQL 5.5 Addressed still reside in 5.1.67

There are many exciting things that MySQL 5.5 features tuning for the following:

- Multicore Processing

  - `May 26, 2011` : [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)
  - `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670)
  - `Sep 20, 2011` : [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968)
- Semisynchronous Replication

  - `Aug 05, 2011` : [Is MySQL Replication Affected by a High-Latency Interconnect?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/is-mysql-replication-affected-by-a-high-latency-interconnect/4390#4390)
  - `Oct 29, 2012` : [Installing and enabling both master and slave semisynchronous plugins on same server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27843/installing-and-enabling-both-master-and-slave-semisynchronous-plugins-on-same-se/27853#27853)
- Buffer Pool Instances : `Feb 12, 2011` : [How do you tune MySQL for a heavy InnoDB workload?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload/1185#1185)

Comment: Rolando, the linked post compares *configured* MySQL. The unconfigured MySQL tests would not provide any useful information, not even a single anecdotal data point

Comment: @LaurynasBiveinis I need to look that post over again. In principle, if all versions were configured the same, the results are still valid. Thank you.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, When you say that we should be using the most stable version, do you mean that we should be using **5.6** now?

Comment: @Pacerier yes the most recent GA version. For MySQL 5.6, use 5.6.21 and higher. For MySQL 5.5, 5.5.40 and higher.

Comment: @Pacerier please keep in mind that I wrote this answer on January 4, 2013. I wrote this answer comparing 5.1 to 5.5. If you look at the question's very first comment, someone commented that 5.6 was not GA. Therefore, the latest 5.5 was stable on January 4, 2013. Today, that would be MySQL 5.6.22.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL **5.1** has reached end of line. This means not more bug fixing. No further improvements.

**5.5** is the stable version, and I can expect it to remain supported for some years to come. **5.5** introduces mostly performance and scale out improvements, and little feature improvement. Which is why I do not understand "that post on this site" -- if you provide a specific link I can relate. It's perfectly possible that some specific scenario would run faster/better on a particular version. But in general you can expect **5.5** to "behave" better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202825/mysql-5-5-perfomance
This is the link to the post

Comment: MySQL 5.1 is not EoL'ed as of today. 5.0 is.

Comment: @LaurynasBiveinis - I stand corrected. Last time I checked last release was Sep 2012; I can see there has been a new release Dec 2012. However, I can verify that a couple bug reports of mine are known "not to be fixed in 5.1", but only in more recent versions (this has led me to the impressions 5.1 is EOL). If (some) 5.1 bug reports are not getting fixed, then I guess 5.1 is as good as EOL.

Comment: I believe they-once they get around fixing community bugs-weigh the fix invasiveness for each active branch individually for the fix-no fix decisions. There is a bunch of bugs fixed in 5.6+ only, or even 5.7 only.

Comment: I think 5.1 will go EOL when 5.6 is GA-released.

Answer (score 1):

One big gotcha for us with 5.1 was UTF-8 support. MySQL's "UTF8" is actually [3-byte UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql).

"UTF8mb4" encoding was added in 5.5.3 and supports 4-byte UTF-8 characters. ([Emoji](https://gist.github.com/mranney/1707371))

You're going to see a lot of projects making 5.5.3 a minimum supported version because of this.

Answer (score 0):

5.1 and 5.5 (and even 4.0) can handle 1000 & 10000 *simple* queries.

Any version will croak on 100 & 1000 *complex* queries.

1000 individual INSERTs will be hard to achieve.  A single (batched) INSERT of 1000 rows will perform at least 10x faster.  Ditto for LOAD DATA.

InnoDB will outperform MyISAM in the scenario you described.  XtraDB may perform even better.

Let's see the SHOW CREATE TABLE and the SELECTs.

Meanwhile, use 5.5, not 5.1.  And, for better performance in the near future, plan on upgrading to 5.6 (Or MariaDB 5.5 or 10.0)

Comment: INSERTs are going to be from different sessions. There can be 1000 Insert at max. That is the worst case. Approx how many INSERTs in 1s can be executed in a satisfactory manner?